# Is it possible to trigger share menu on smartphones (via HTML/JS)?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, share

Is there an existing possibility to trigger the share functionality in local browsers on smartphones via HTML or JavaScript?

Of course there are many services which provide a share button. But when I e.g. want to share a website on facebook, I need to be logged in to facebook in the browser I am currently using.

Almost all browsers got an own share functionality build in, which triggers a system menu to choose which app you want to use to share:

[image: System share menu in android os]

This question is about: How to trigger this menu?

I know it is possible to trigger a phone call with a specified prefix in href attribute of links, like `tel:` or `callto:`. Maybe such a shortcut for this share menu is also existing? Or some javascript code? Or a totally different way how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I added this as all answers seems outdated by 2018-07-16.

It is possible, but only in a few browsers ([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share)), achieved througth the one method API in `navigator`:

```
navigator
    .share({
        title: document.title,
        text: 'Hello World',
        url: window.location.href
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share! '))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Google's reference: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/navigator-share

Also, there was a thing called **Web Intends** which is a dead project, you should go with `navigator.share` instead.

Comment: Worked perfectly! This is the valid answer.

Comment: It works also in Silk. This browser should be mentioned too.

Answer (score 51):

It is possible *with a big catch*. Currently only available in Chrome for Android, Samsung internet and on Safari (desktop and mobile). And support is coming to Edge and Chrome on desktop http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-share

```
if (navigator.share) {
  navigator.share({
    title: document.title,
    text: "Hello World",
    url: window.location.href
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
  .catch(error => console.log('Error sharing:', error));
}
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/navigator-share

Answer (score 14):

It's now possible with the [Web Share API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share)!

However, it isn't widely supported as of yet. Currently, it's only available in Safari (mobile and desktop), and Chrome for Android. See [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-share) for details.

According to [Introducing the Web Share API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share) on Google Developers, there are several things to keep in mind:

- your page needs to be served over HTTPS
- you can only call `navigator.share(…)` in response to a user action, such as a click (i.e., you can't call it on page load)
- you should feature-detect it in case it's not available on your users' platform (e.g., via `navigator.share !== undefined`)

The Google Developers article also notes that URLs shared with the Share API need not be on your own domain—you can share any URL.

Putting that all together, you could use something like this which uses the Share API if it's available, and falls back to sending an email if it's not<sup>*</sup>:

```js
function createShareButton() {
  const btn = document.createElement("button");

  const title = document.title;
  const text = "Check this out!";
  const url = window.location.href;

  btn.innerText = "share" in navigator ? "Share" : "Share via e-mail";

  btn.onclick = () => {
    if (navigator.share !== undefined) {
      navigator
        .share({
          title,
          text,
          url
        })
        .then(() => console.log("Shared!"))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    } else {
      window.location = `mailto:?subject=${title}&body=${text}%0A${url}`;
    }
  };

  return btn;
}

document.title = "Demo";
document.body.appendChild(createShareButton());
```

<sub>*: Please do consider using a more appropriate fallback, (e.g., social sharing) depending on your use case.</sub>

Answer (score 11):

**Answered Apr 10 2013**

To my knowledge, there is no such implementation in current browsers on mobile OS's. Since the question interested me - a google search revealed there is work being done in this direction:

- https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/web-intents/raw-file/tip/spec/Overview.html
- http://webintents.org/

Sorry - I do not know a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and I wrote a function to have pretty content to share and observe the asynchronous side effects:

```
const shareContact = async (title, content) => {
  const text = `${title}

${content}`;

  try {
    await navigator.share({
      text,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WebView.addJavascriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) method for android.

First you will need to write a class which fires the intent to open the share menu([take a look here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/)) and then implement that class using the addJavascriptInterface() call. After that all you need to do is call the method from your Javascript.

Comment: I'm not familiar with writing apps on android. But this sounds like writing an app.