# How to implement share functionality in IPhone browser?

Tags: javascript, ios

How to implement share functionality in Iphone browser?
below code working fine in Android mobile browser like chrome.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

```
function fnShare(){
    if (navigator.share) {
    navigator.share({
    title: 'Web Fundamentals',
    text: 'Check out Web Fundamentals it rocks!',
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/web',
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
    }else{
    alert('navigator.share not supported');
    }
    }
```

I tried in iphone (chrome browser) but it's not working.

Comment: you mean safari?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to trigger share menu on smartphones (via HTML/JS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921262/is-it-possible-to-trigger-share-menu-on-smartphones-via-html-js)

Comment: Yes safari browser

Comment: currently, only chrome on iOS support this navigator.share

Comment: I tried in chrome browser but still facing issue.

Comment: is it possible web share functionality in iPhone?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Web Share API](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/) for that.

There's a [great article from a source I trust explaining it](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-the-web-share-api/).

They explain the overall idea (limitations and requirements) and provide the following demo:

```js
const shareButton = document.querySelector('.share-button');
const shareDialog = document.querySelector('.share-dialog');
const closeButton = document.querySelector('.close-button');

shareButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (navigator.share) { 
   navigator.share({
      title: 'WebShare API Demo',
      url: 'https://codepen.io/ayoisaiah/pen/YbNazJ'
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Thanks for sharing!');
    })
    .catch(console.error);
    } else {
        shareDialog.classList.add('is-open');
    }
});

closeButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  shareDialog.classList.remove('is-open');
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,San Francisco,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Ubuntu,Roboto,Noto,Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

button, .button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover, .button:hover {
  border-color: #cdd;
}

.share-button, .copy-link {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.share-button, .share-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.share-dialog {
  display: none;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.share-dialog.is-open {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.targets {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.close-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.close-button svg {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.pen-url {
  margin-right: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="share-dialog">
  <header>
    <h3 class="dialog-title">Share this pen</h3>
    <button class="close-button"><svg><use href="#close"></use></svg></button>
  </header>
  <div class="targets">
    <a class="button">
      <svg>
        <use href="#facebook"></use>
      </svg>
      <span>Facebook</span>
    </a>
    
    <a class="button">
      <svg>
        <use href="#twitter"></use>
      </svg>
      <span>Twitter</span>
    </a>
    
    <a class="button">
      <svg>
        <use href="#linkedin"></use>
      </svg>
      <span>LinkedIn</span>
    </a>
    
    <a class="button">
      <svg>
        <use href="#email"></use>
      </svg>
      <span>Email</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="link">
    <div class="pen-url">https://codepen.io/ayoisaiah/pen/YbNazJ</div>
    <button class="copy-link">Copy Link</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="share-button" type="button" title="Share this article">
  <svg>
    <use href="#share-icon"></use>
  </svg>
  <span>Share</span>
</button>

<svg class="hidden">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="share-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-share"><path d="M4 12v8a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-8"></path><polyline points="16 6 12 2 8 6"></polyline><line x1="12" y1="2" x2="12" y2="15"></line></symbol>
    
    <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#3b5998" stroke="#3b5998" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-facebook"><path d="M18 2h-3a5 5 0 0 0-5 5v3H7v4h3v8h4v-8h3l1-4h-4V7a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h3z"></path></symbol>
    
    <symbol id="twitter" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#1da1f2" stroke="#1da1f2" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-twitter"><path d="M23 3a10.9 10.9 0 0 1-3.14 1.53 4.48 4.48 0 0 0-7.86 3v1A10.66 10.66 0 0 1 3 4s-4 9 5 13a11.64 11.64 0 0 1-7 2c9 5 20 0 20-11.5a4.5 4.5 0 0 0-.08-.83A7.72 7.72 0 0 0 23 3z"></path></symbol>
    
    <symbol id="email" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#777" stroke="#fafafa" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-mail"><path d="M4 4h16c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2v12c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2H4c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2V6c0-1.1.9-2 2-2z"></path><polyline points="22,6 12,13 2,6"></polyline></symbol>
    
    <symbol id="linkedin" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#0077B5" stroke="#0077B5" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-linkedin"><path d="M16 8a6 6 0 0 1 6 6v7h-4v-7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2 2 2 0 0 0-2 2v7h-4v-7a6 6 0 0 1 6-6z"></path><rect x="2" y="9" width="4" height="12"></rect><circle cx="4" cy="4" r="2"></circle></symbol>
    
    <symbol id="close" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-square"><rect x="3" y="3" width="18" height="18" rx="2" ry="2"></rect><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line></symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your code snippet just copies the fallback code from the article. The Web Share API is simply the call to navigator.share(), which you didn't even include