# How to embed share dialog to web page in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to include the share button on my web page. By using this share button clients can share the page through different social media ex- what's app,fb,Instagram,mail etc.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to trigger share menu on smartphones (via HTML/JS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921262/is-it-possible-to-trigger-share-menu-on-smartphones-via-html-js)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `navigator.share` method to invoke the native sharing mechanism. The application should be running in a web browser or a web view.

```
const shareData = {
  title: 'My Data',
  text: 'Here I Am',
  url: 'example.com',
}

await navigator.share(shareData)
resultPara.textContent = 'I shared my data successfully'
```